# Text Overlapping over Image

Tags: css

The structure of my image and paragraphs is as follows:

```
<p class="All-Book-Text">Maecenas iaculis, ipsum at tempor placerat, orci ligula aliquam enim, sit amet sagittis turpis enim sit amet lorem. Praesent dapibus pretium felis, et tempus nibh posuere a.</p>


<div class="_idGenObjectLayout-3">
    <div id="_idContainer062" class="ObjExpOpt-Images">
        <img class="_idGenObjectAttribute-1" src="image/animal.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

<p class="All-Book-Text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet elementum ex, a porttitor arcu vulputate vitae. Mauris ac finibus nisi. Etiam at tellus vitae quam pretium eleifend. Donec at dictum nisi, id condimentum dui. Donec in tortor ipsum. Etiam sit amet turpis vulputate, maximus erat in, lacinia leo. Cras placerat lobortis fermentum. Phasellus vulputate libero et pellentesque mattis. Aenean tristique ante egestas nibh aliquet, a sagittis sem aliquam. Aenean sit amet diam elementum, cursus arcu non, vehicula lorem. Sed vitae ante id augue consectetur euismod. Suspendisse ac metus ut tortor mollis semper eget eu mi. Vivamus eleifend leo at felis bibendum rutrum. Proin condimentum consectetur velit, at tristique elit accumsan vel.</p>
```

When the page renders, the text of the lower paragraph overlaps over the image. How can I prevent this and make sure that the distance between the image and the parapgraph is  5 px and no overlap occurs whatsoever. Thanks!

Here's a live demo with my problem http://jsfiddle.net/zvnjnxnf/

Comment: Without your CSS how are we supposed to know what's going on?

Comment: @DavidThomas My Apologies. Since I could not figure out which css was causing an issue, I pasted my entire file here http://jsfiddle.net/zvnjnxnf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks ok here: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/u4101zfe/)

```
p {display: inline}
img {display: block}
```

Comment: set #_idContainer062 {height:auto}, see http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/zvnjnxnf/1/ The image's wrapper has a height of 134px, so the paragraph is starting after it. The inner image is bigger and overfloats, that's why it seems that the text ovelaps the image (not the image's wrapper)

Comment: Oh I see. Is there any way I can override all these in a master tag or something. I have hundreds of images and all have different idContainer like #_idContainer660, #_idContainer661 and so on. However all the images have  the same class i.e _idGenObjectAttribute-1

Comment: You have to select the image parent element (div). In your jsFiddle, the div has a class "ObjExpOpt-Images". So, you can set this css rule: div.ObjExpOpt-Images {height: auto!important}

Comment: You can also use jQuery if you cannot set a class to the div elements like so: $('img._idGenObjectAttribute-1').parent('div').css({'height':'auto'});

Comment: Oh my! It worked. Thanks a ton. Can you help me fix the spaces here too http://jsfiddle.net/zvnjnxnf/3/ . I want it to look elegant and right now it is very cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should remove all the style for **All-Book-Text** and **_idGenObjectLayout-3**

then add the following css :

._idGenObjectLayout-3{

padding : 5px;

}